# What is the basic difference between the ToString() and Convert.ToString()?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can any help me in order to understand difference between convert.tostring() and tostring()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is huge.
[ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) is method inherited from Object.
Convert.ToString is a method from [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.aspx)

Convert simply cast your object into IConvertible and calls appropriate method.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this post [By John Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2003/11/06/36308.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

if you invoke `ToString()` on `null` string it will throw `NullReferenceException` and Convert.ToString() does not throw  `NullReferenceException`,instead you get empty string

Answer (score 0):

ToString can not hold the Null value.
Convert.ToString can hold the Null value

Answer (score 0):

If you use `obj.ToString()` and obj is null then here you will get an `NullReferenceException`.
 While if you are using `Convert.ToString(obj)` then it will not throw an exception if obj is null.